# Lock state multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have multiple rich text editors on single page.
There is autosaving of both done by ajax calls that are separate.
Each text editor is saved on focus lost or when focus is inside of editor every 20 seconds.

When editor is not saved and user navigates away I am showing "navigate away warning".

Now I need to manage warning that when one editor is in the middle of saving and the other one finishes earlier warning will not be removed.

What I have now:

```
editorOneIsSaving=true;
SetNavigateAwayNotification();
$.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'json', url: "/SaveEditorOne",
         data: mypostdata1,
         success: function (msg) {
             editorOneIsSaving = false;
             if (!editorTwoIsSaving) {
                 RemoveNavigatingAwayNotification();
             }
            updateSavedInfo();
         },
        });
```

For second editor:

```
editroTwoIsSaving=true;
SetNavigateAwayNotification();
$.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'json', url: "/SaveEditorTwo",
         data: mypostdata2,
         success: function (msg) {
             editorTwoIsSaving = false;
             if (!editorOneIsSaving) {
                 RemoveNavigatingAwayNotification();
             }
            updateSavedInfo();
         }
        });
```

I was looking into adding object to array or list but it is not really nice in javascript. This way I would know who is the owner of lock or if there would be more editors I could make sure that same editor is not taking lock multiple times.

Maybe I am just overthinking and I should go with simply counter which if is 0 then remove navigate away.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add a counter to each ajax call to save.
You increment the counter before sending the data to the server and decrement it in the promise.

something like the following

```
function showSavingMessage(){
     //code to show message
}

function removeSavingMessage(){
     // code to remove message
}



var ctr = 0;
function saveData(){
    showSavingMessage();
    ctr++;
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'json', url: "/SaveEditorXXX",
         data: mypostdata2,
         success: function (msg) {
             if (ctr > 0){
                 ctr--;
             } else {
                 removeSavingMessage(); 
             }

         }
    });
}
```

You can handle errors any way you like. may be change the "saving" message to error message.

You can also pass the url and the data to the saveData function to make it reusable, so you have a single function with the Ajax code.